# Should React component method reference be cleared in component unmount?

Tags: reactjs, redux-thunk

lets assume something lile this:

```
handleClick = () => {
  dispatchThunkAction(this.someMethod),
}

someMethod = () => {
  //do something
}
```

`dispatchThunkAction` fires http request.
once done, thunk action calls back `someMethod` thats passed to it.

should `someMethod` be set to `null` in `componentWiUnmount` for the case unmount happens in the middle of http (or any other async operation) call?

so, like

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.someMethod = null;
}
```

so that garbage collector knows it can pick it up immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the method to `null` will not help, but you could create an instance variable called e.g. `_isMounted` that you set to `false` in `componentDidUnmount` and check that this variable is `true` before you do anything in `someMethod`.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  _isMounted = true

  handleClick = () => {
    dispatchThunkAction(this.someMethod)
  }

  someMethod = () => {
    if (!this._isMounted) {
      return
    }

    //do something
  }

  componentDidUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false
  }  

  // ...
}
```

Comment: so you are effectively saying that component cannot be really unmounted for as long as thunk action keeps reference to its method? if i understand correctly? (null-check before calling it on thunk action side is not my concern atm)

Comment: @deezg The component will still be unmounted as usual even with the `_isMounted` instance variable, but you keep a value indicating that it has been unmounted.

Comment: ok, so there are 2 different things here: unmounted (as react component state) and ready to be garbage collected. i guess what you are saying is it will be unmounted but not ready for garbage collection for as long as thunk action keeps reference to `someMethod`. is that correct statement?

Comment: @deezg Yes, that's right. The garbage collection will resolve itself eventually, but not checking if the component is still mounted before using `setState` will result in a warning.

Comment: right right, now it makes perfect sense. thanks for clarifications!